# World clock with localtimes.info not working on my angular js app

Tags: angularjs, clock

I tried to place a world clock with 5 countries in my website, which I developed using `AngularJs`.

I used `localtimes.info` website which provides an embed link. It doesn't work for me, but it works with a general HTML page without angularjs. Here is my code. Do anyone have such experience or what is the best way to display 5 different **countries clock** on my angularjs web application. Please help me. thanks in advance

```
<div style="margin: 15px 0px 0px; display: inline-block; text-align: center;">
  <div style="display: inline-block; padding: 2px 4px; margin: 0px 0px 5px; border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); text-align: center; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
    <a href="http://localtimes.info/difference" style="text-decoration: none; font-size: 13px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">World Clock</a> 
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localtimes.info/world_clock2.php?&cp1_Hex=000000&cp2_Hex=FFFFFF&cp3_Hex=3ea8cf&fwdt=104&ham=0&hbg=0&hfg=0&sid=0&mon=0&wek=0&wkf=0&sep=0&widget_number=21000&lcid=SNXX0006,USNY0996,UKXX0085,INXX0096,CHXX0049"></script>
</div>
```

Comment: angular strips out script tags from templates. You would need to use a custom directive for this. Also that script uses `document.write()` which can't be used after initial page load as it wipes out the whole page

Comment: what is the solution for this??

Comment: Find an api that you can use to get the times and display them with alternate approach that fits angular methodology